# Javascript Sha256 vs PHP Sha256: Line breaks create different hash?

Tags: javascript, php, hash, sha256

I am getting two different hash values when line breaks are added.

On this site http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator there is a JavaScript Sha256 hash generator.

When I run a hash on "onetwo" I get:

```
25b6746d5172ed6352966a013d93ac846e1110d5a25e8f183b5931f4688842a1
```

When I use PHP

```
echo hash('sha256', 'onetwo');
```

I get:

```
25b6746d5172ed6352966a013d93ac846e1110d5a25e8f183b5931f4688842a1
```

But when I run a hash from the URL that includes a line break (return) like:

```
'one
two'
```

I get:

```
21066d108d5319ecb5a1fc4454f42ef22fc5f1c7df49c31d90294950e0ea8b2c
```

But when I use PHP I get:

```
29a776bb35efe730dabb1b1d3ad74dbf80cc3e9009e168241798ea73adca3dcf
```

Can any one point out why this is so?  Why does adding line breaks give different results?

Here is my PHP/HTML code as you will see I am using a form and submitting the data to be hashed.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Sha256 Hash</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="float: left;">
      Start here and insert text below to be hashed.<br />
      <form name="submit hash" action="" method="POST">
        <textarea name="text" style="border: thin solid #000; width: 500px; padding: 10px; height: 500px;"><? if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') echo $_POST['text']; ?></textarea>
        <br style="clear: both;" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
    <? if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'): ?>
    <div style="border: thin solid #000; margin: 10px; padding: 10px; float: left;">
      <br />sha256:&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><?= hash('sha256',$_POST['text']); ?></b><br />
    </div>
    <? endif; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: As a side note you shouldn't be using short tags in PHP (`<? ... ?>`) as their use is discouraged for portability reasons, see http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: @SteveWilford, Noted Thank you!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@mrjoltcola is right.

When getting the value from the textarea the new lines are \r\n (CRLF).

You can validate this in your php code by printing the url encoded version of the string that you read like that:

```
var_dump(urlencode($_POST['text']));
```

This will print `string(12) "one%0D%0Atwo"` if you enter

```
one
two
```

where %0D is the html code for carriage return and %0A for line feed as you can see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Now to get the same hash as in the [javascript version](http://www.xorbin.com/tools/sha256-hash-calculator) you have to remove the carriage return. You can do that it in php like that:

```
$string_to_be_hashed = preg_replace( "/\r\n/", "\n", $_POST['text'] );
```

Then, if you hash the `$string_to_be_hashed` you will get the expected result.

In the javascript version this happens also internally. If you check the [hash256 source code](http://www.xorbin.com/javascript/webtoolkit.sha256.js) there is a `Utf8Encode(string)` function where the first line is `string = string.replace(/\r\n/g,"\n");` which is essentialy the same.

Comment: WOW, great answer and very in depth.  I gave you the green check because you were more in depth than mrjoltcola.  Now I have a question.  So is it important to replace \r\n with \n or is the javascript site doing it just as a preference?

Comment: I guess it is a matter of preference. Windows systems represent new line as `\r\n` while Linux represent it as `\n`. Other systems use other representations as mentioned [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations). My opinion is that if you are going to hash a file (by letting the user upload it or something) then don't change anything. Otherwise, if you want to create something similar to the javascript site then you could choose a default behavior but also provide a checkbox or something to let the user select a different new line representation.

Answer (score 3):

I would expect it is the difference between carriage return and line feeds ( \r\n vs \n )

Your PHP inline test string probably only has `\n`

The web one probably has `\r\n`

Secondly, these are considered part of the content. Hashing it doesn't ignore it.

Comment: thank you for the answer... I ended up giving the green to Master_ex because he really went into depth.  I would also give you a vote up except I don't qualify yet for voting :-(